# HID devicce: Trapping input on windows 10

Tags: c#, windows, user-interface, winapi

On a Windows 10 machine I have a USB touch-screen device. This is an external device that you mount on a regualr (non-touch) monitor and it adds touch support to it. Normally, it uses a HID interface to interact with windows.

I would like to trap these touch events in my application, instead of them firing on other open windows. My first approach was to open a full screen app, and trap the regualr window touch events. However, I would prefer that I can still use this computer for other things.
So I am looking for a method in which I don't need to have a fullscreen window occupying the entire screen. Prefereably, I would like to "trap" these events in my app so that they do not reach the Windows desktop at all. Sort of like what virtualbox does when it traps the mouse.
Is this the right way to go about doing this? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468895(v=vs.85).aspx

Are there higher level approaches to this?
Choice of language is not an issue: C#/C++/Python/Java/....

Comment: Unclear, what *"instead of them arriving on the OS"* is supposed to mean. All input arrives at the OS.

Comment: I want to prevent the events from arriving at other "regualr" ux apps. (I don't want the inputs from these device to cause regular clicks on other windows)

Comment: Raw Input is the only way that allows you to identify the input source by device. While it allows you to listen to (system-wide) input, it cannot be used to (selectively) block input. Blocking input requires a hook, and I'm not aware of a hook that would intercept genuine touch input. A mouse hook can intercept mouse messages generated by the system in response to touch input to allow applications without a dedicated touch input interface to be still used with a touch input device.